# make UIView locked / untapped / disabled for loading

Tags: uiview, uigesturerecognizer, tap

I am using activityIndicator view, and I want to "lock" the uiView for that period. The problem is - how to lock or make uiview do not receive some taps, and after this hot to turn it back?

Answer (score 0):

Show identity inspector--->Document--->Lock--->select "all property"

Please use above steps in Xcode and lock your controls in xib. Once we lock the view we'll not move or tab the controls in the screen.

Note: We can see this utility in right side of Xcode and third menu from left.